# When I use Thrift to serialize map in C++ to disk, and then de-serialize it using Python, I do not get back the same object

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, thrift

Summary: when I use Thrift to serialize map in C++ to disk, and then de-serialize it using Python, I do not get back the same object.

A minimal example to reproduce to the problem is in Github repo https://github.com/brunorijsman/reproduce-thrift-crash

Clone this repo on Ubuntu (tested on 16.04) and follow the instructions at the top of the file reproduce.sh

I have the following Thrift model file, which (as you can see) contains a map indexed by a struct:

```
struct Coordinate {
    1: required i32 x;
    2: required i32 y;
}

struct Terrain {
    1: required map<Coordinate, i32> altitude_samples;
}
```

I use the following C++ code to create an object with 3 coordinates in the map (see the repo for complete code for all snippets below):

```
Terrain terrain;
add_sample_to_terrain(terrain, 10, 10, 100);
add_sample_to_terrain(terrain, 20, 20, 200);
add_sample_to_terrain(terrain, 30, 30, 300);
```

where:

```
void add_sample_to_terrain(Terrain& terrain, int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t altitude)
{
    Coordinate coordinate;
    coordinate.x = x;
    coordinate.y = y;
    std::pair<Coordinate, int32_t> sample(coordinate, altitude);
    terrain.altitude_samples.insert(sample);
}
```

I use the following C++ code to serialize an object to disk:

```
shared_ptr<TFileTransport> transport(new TFileTransport("terrain.dat"));
shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
terrain.write(protocol.get());
```

Important note: for this to work correctly, I had to implement the function Coordinate::operator<. Thrift does generate the declaration for the Coordinate::operator< but does not generate the implementation of Coordinate::operator<. The reason for this is that Thrift does not understand the semantics of the struct and hence cannot guess the correct implementation of the comparison operator. This is discussed at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201007.mbox/%3C4C4E08BD.8030407@facebook.com%3E

```
// Thrift generates the declaration but not the implementation of operator< because it has no way
// of knowning what the criteria for the comparison are. So, provide the implementation here.
bool Coordinate::operator<(const Coordinate& other) const
{
    if (x < other.x) {
        return true;
    } else if (x > other.x) {
        return false;
    } else if (y < other.y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, finally, I use the following Python code to de-serialize the same object from disk:

```
file = open("terrain.dat", "rb")
transport = thrift.transport.TTransport.TFileObjectTransport(file)
protocol = thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
terrain = Terrain()
terrain.read(protocol)
print(terrain)
```

This Python program outputs:

```
Terrain(altitude_samples=None)
```

In other words, the de-serialized Terrain contains no terrain_samples, instead of the expected dictionary with 3 coordinates.

I am 100% sure that the file terrain.dat contains valid data: I also de-serialized the same data using C++ and in that case, I *do* get the expected results (see repo for details)

I suspect that this has something to do with the comparison operator.

I gut feeling is that I should have done something similar in Python with respect to the comparison operator as I did in C++. But I don't know what that missing something would be.

Additional information added on 19-Sep-2018:

Here is a hexdump of the encoding produced by the C++ encoding program:

```
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 01 00 00 00 0D 02 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 0C    ................
00000010: 01 00 00 00 08 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 00 00    ................
00000020: 00 08 02 00 00 00 00 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A    ................
00000030: 01 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 00 00 02 04 00 00 00 00    ................
00000040: 00 00 0A 01 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 64    ...............d
00000050: 01 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 00 00 01 04 00 00 00 00    ................
00000060: 00 00 14 01 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 00 00 02 04 00    ................
00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 14 01 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00    ................
00000080: 00 00 C8 01 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 00 00 01 04 00    ..H.............
00000090: 00 00 00 00 00 1E 01 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 00 00    ................
000000a0: 02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 01 00 00 00 00 04 00    ................
000000b0: 00 00 00 00 01 2C 01 00 00 00 00                   .....,.....
```

The first 4 bytes are 01 00 00 00

Using a debugger to step through the Python decoding function reveals that:

- This is being decoded as a struct (which is expected)
- The first byte 01 is interpreted as the field type. 01 means field type VOID.
- The next two bytes are interpreted as the field id. 00 00 means field ID 0.
- For field type VOID, nothing else is read and we continue to the next field.
- The next byte is interpreted as the field type. 00 means STOP.
- We top reading data for the struct.
- The final result is an empty struct.

All off the above is consistent with the information at https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/doc/specs/thrift-binary-protocol.md which describes the Thrift binary encoding format

My conclusion thus far is that the C++ encoder appears to produce an "incorrect" binary encoding (I put incorrect in quotes because certainly something as blatant as that would have been discovered by lots of other people, so I am sure that I am still missing something).

Additional information added on 19-Sep-2018:

It appears that the C++ implementation of TFileTransport has the concept of "events" when writing to disk.

The output which is written to disk is divided into a sequence of "events" where each "event" is preceded by a 4-byte length field of the event, followed by the contents of the event.

Looking at the hexdump above, the first couple of events are:

`0100 0000 0d` : Event length 1, event value `0d`

`02 0000 0000 01` : Event length 2, event value `00 01`

Etc.

The Python implementation of TFileTransport does not understand this concept of events when parsing the file.

It appears that the problem is one of the following two:

1) Either the C++ code should not be inserting these event lengths into the encoded file,

2) Or the Python code should understand these event lengths when decoding the file.

Note that all these event lengths make the C++ encode file much larger than the Python encoded file.

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

If I were you I would clone the thrift python library, and change the TFileTransportObject in https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/py/src/transport/TTransport.py , repackage and install into your environment.

Comment: That would solve the problem for me alone, but wouldn't we need to solve this issue in the main repo? It seems that the whole point of an encoding and decoding framework such as Thrift is to make it safe to encode an object using one programming language and decode it in a different programming language.

Comment: It seems to me that we are caught between a rock and a hard place. Changing the encoding format for Python would change a rare problem (cannot encode in Thrift C++ and decode in Thrift Python) into a common problem (cannot encode in old version of Thrift Python and decode in new version of Thrift Python)

Comment: @BrunoRijsman: Of course you should [file a ticket and submit a PR](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute). After all, that's how OSS really works. It's not only about forking as some people might believe. BTW, thanks for tracking this down.

Comment: "*It appears that the C++ implementation of TFileTransport has the concept of "events" when writing to disk*"  --  That sounds suspicious to me. The contents of the "wire" data should not change if transports are switched. They are intended to be dependent on the chosen protocols only (for this purpose we can safely ignore TFramedTransport).

Comment: @JensG I agree that it is "not a good thing" that the format in a file is different from the format on a TCP connection. But that is how it is today. Actually, I was surprised by the (overly?) complex implementation of writing to a file in C++. There is one thread that encodes the data in "events" (chunks of data). That thread puts the events on a queue. Another thread reads the events from the queue and actually writes to disk. No idea what the purpose of using 2 threads is.

Comment: @JensG A couple of days ago I filed THRIFT-4638 for this.

Comment: Looks as if the Java implementation also has these "events" and they are intended to make it a random access file: https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TFileTransport.java ... [THRIFT-377](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-377) is the ticket for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly C++ TFileTransport is not totally portable and will not work with Python's TFileObjectTransport. If you switch to C++ TSimpleFileTransport it will work as expected, with Python TFileObjectTransport and with Java TSimpleFileTransport.

Take a look at the examples here:

https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/tree/master/part2/types/complex

They do pretty much exactly what you are attempting in Java and Python and you can find examples with C++, Java and Python here (though they add a zip compression layer):

https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/tree/master/part2/types/zip

Another caution however would be against the use of complex key types. Complex key types require (as you discovered) comparators but will flat out not work with some languages. I might suggest, for example:

```
map<x,map<y,alt>>
```

giving the same utility but eliminating a whole class of possible problems (and no need for comparators).

Comment: Interesting. Can you give an example of a language where the complex comparisons flat out don't work?

Comment: It is not only the comparisons that are a problem, some languages just don't allow complex keys, Perl for example. Thrift itself does not promise support for complex map keys, so the onus is on you to test support, language by language. Further, you have not only the language to deal with (for example Ruby Hashes require hash and eql? methods to be overridden to provide meaningful behavior with complex keys) but also the Thrift generator for the language, which may not support complex keys even if the language can.

Comment: @Bruno Any reason you have not accepted this answer?

Comment: Sorry, had moved on to other things and forgot to do so